# How to handle ambiguous field in my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT TB.ID, Latitude, Longitude, 111151.29341326 * SQRT( POW( -6 - `Latitude` , 2 ) + POW( 106 - `Longitude` , 2 ) * COS( -6 * 0.017453292519943 ) * COS( `Latitude` * 0.017453292519943 ) ) AS Distance
FROM `tablebusiness` AS TB
JOIN `tablecity` AS TC ON TB.City = TC.City
JOIN `businessestag` AS BC ON BC.BusinessID = TB.ID
JOIN `businessesdistricts` AS BD ON BD.BusinessID = TB.ID
JOIN `tabledistrict` AS TD ON TD.ID = BD.District
WHERE (
`Title` LIKE '%restaurant%'
OR `Street` LIKE '%restaurant%'
OR TB.City LIKE '%restaurant%'
OR BC.Tag LIKE '%restaurant%'
OR TD.District LIKE '%restaurant%'
)
AND (
- 6.0917668133836 < `Latitude`
AND `Latitude` < - 5.9082331866164
AND 105.90823318662 < `Longitude`
AND `Longitude` < 106.09176681338
)
ORDER BY Distance
LIMIT 0, 100
```

This mysql went through

Then I want to look based on building too.

So I did, like someone suggested do

```
SELECT
  TB.ID,
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  111151.29341326 * SQRT(POW(-6 - `TB.Latitude`, 2) + POW(106 - `TB.Longitude`, 2) * COS(-6 * 0.017453292519943) * COS(`TB.Latitude` * 0.017453292519943)) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  JOIN `tablecity` AS TC
    ON TB.City = TC.City
  JOIN `businessestag` AS BC
    ON BC.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `businessesdistricts` AS BD
    ON BD.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `tabledistrict` AS TD
    ON TD.ID = BD.District
  LEFT JOIN `tablebusiness` TBuilding
    ON TBuilding.ID = TB.Building
WHERE
  (`Title` LIKE '%restaurant%' OR `Street` LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TB.City LIKE '%restaurant%' 
    OR BC.Tag LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TD.District LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TBuilding.Title LIKE '%restaurant%')
  AND (-6.0917668133836 < `TB.Latitude` AND `TB.Latitude` < -5.9082331866164 
    AND 105.90823318662 < `TB.Longitude` AND `TB.Longitude` < 106.09176681338) 
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 100
```

Then I got a message that Latitude fields is ambiguous.

What should I do?

I did the obvious adding TB. before latitude

```
explain SELECT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude,
  111151.29341326 * SQRT(POW(-6 - `TB.Latitude`, 2) + POW(106 - `TB.Longitude`, 2) * COS(-6 * 0.017453292519943) * COS(`TB.Latitude` * 0.017453292519943)) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  JOIN `tablecity` AS TC
    ON TB.City = TC.City
  JOIN `businessestag` AS BC
    ON BC.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `businessesdistricts` AS BD
    ON BD.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `tabledistrict` AS TD
    ON TD.ID = BD.District
  LEFT JOIN `tablebusiness` TBuilding
    ON TBuilding.ID = TB.Building
WHERE
  (`Title` LIKE '%restaurant%' OR `Street` LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TB.City LIKE '%restaurant%' 
    OR BC.Tag LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TD.District LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TBuilding.Title LIKE '%restaurant%')
  AND (-6.0917668133836 < `TB.Latitude` AND `TB.Latitude` < -5.9082331866164 
    AND 105.90823318662 < `TB.Longitude` AND `TB.Longitude` < 106.09176681338) 
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 100
```

And now the error is #1054 - Unknown column 'TB.Latitude' in 'field list'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you need to prepend `Latitude` you are referring to with `TB` alias

```
SELECT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
...
```

It may happen, that `Longitude` will also be ambiguous, so I'd suggest prepending it with appropriate alias as well.

**Upd.:**

I would additionally suggest you to remove quotes surrounding `TB.Latitude` and `TB.Latitude` as those are causing "Unknown column" error.

Comment: I did that and I got a message saying TB.Latitude not found

Comment: That should be connected with quoting `TB.Latitude` and `TB.Latitude`. Could you, please, try unquoting them?

Comment: Okay I'll try. What's the point of quoting anyway? Should we quote?

Comment: It works (after fixing some error). So why do my programmer use ' in the first place.

Comment: Quoting could help in case you are using reserved words as column names, e.g. `user`, `where`, `select` etc.
If this is the case, you could still go with something like ` TB ` . ` User `, but in this particular case quoting is an overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Put the Alias of the table before, like TB.Latitude

Answer (score 0):

Since in the second query you are joining `tablebusiness` twice, it creates ambiguity.

So in order to remove the ambiguity you will have to also include the alias of the table from which you want the columns `Latitude and Longitude`.

The correct query would be -

```
SELECT TB.ID,
       TB.Latitude,
       TB.Longitude,
<everything else remains the same.>
```

Comment: I did that. Now I got not found.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is the one suggested by Li0LiQ

So I don't select this as the answer.

Just for the record, the final case is and it works. Again. Thanks Li0LiQ. Your answer is the selected answer.

```
explain SELECT
  TB.ID,
  TB.Latitude,
  TB.Longitude,
  111151.29341326 * SQRT(POW(-6 - TB.Latitude, 2) + POW(106 - TB.Longitude, 2) * COS(-6 * 0.017453292519943) * COS(TB.Latitude * 0.017453292519943)) AS Distance
FROM
  `tablebusiness` AS TB
  JOIN `tablecity` AS TC
    ON TB.City = TC.City
  JOIN `businessestag` AS BC
    ON BC.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `businessesdistricts` AS BD
    ON BD.BusinessID = TB.ID
  JOIN `tabledistrict` AS TD
    ON TD.ID = BD.District
  LEFT JOIN `tablebusiness` TBuilding
    ON TBuilding.ID = TB.Building
WHERE
  (TB.Title LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TB.Street LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TB.City LIKE '%restaurant%' 
    OR BC.Tag LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TD.District LIKE '%restaurant%' OR TBuilding.Title LIKE '%restaurant%')
  AND (-6.0917668133836 < TB.Latitude AND TB.Latitude < -5.9082331866164 
    AND 105.90823318662 < TB.Longitude AND TB.Longitude < 106.09176681338) 
ORDER BY
  Distance
LIMIT
  0, 100
```